# Fed up with trolling on this site

Tags: discussion

I am fed up with the trolling on this site.

These posts:

- [How should I discuss the cheerleading squad uniform policy with the coach?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/how-should-i-discuss-the-cheerleading-squad-uniform-policy-with-the-coach)
- https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26397/16-yo-son-obsessed-with-oreos-and-doritos-wont-eat-what-we-give-him-spends-a
- [My daughter's friend faked having cancer - our daughter found out via Facebook and is devastated. What do we do?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/my-daughters-friend-faked-having-cancer-our-daughter-found-out-via-facebook-a)

(the entire text was on GMInsidenews, but the mods removed it there).

Can the mods do something about it?

Comment: I am unsure of why you are 'fed up' - can you clarify? The posts you refer to below are all within the last day, and you yourself have only just registered - so it's not like this is a long term issue.

Comment: I would cosign to @Rory sentiments, seems like you just joined, and the posts are recent. Did you read through all the questions? I actually think the site is great and helpful having joined just recently. My views though. I also tried to pin point the trolls but couldn't see. People have different opinions, if I posted a question I would be open minded definitely. I have seen trolling on twitter though. :)

Comment: what's GMInsidenews? A site for trolls? What makes you sure these questions where trolling (entirely possible IMO)?

Comment: If someone can explain to me how these are "trolling"? I see two questions (the middle one seems to be down. I fail to see anything objectionable, but I am fully aware that I could be missing something. Can someone point out the problem to me? Thank you.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, some people like to lurk...

Answer (score 3):

Mods can deal with anything once we see it - you can do your part by flagging anything you see that requires mod attention, or once you have gained some more rep you can downvote and vote to close posts yourself.

Comment: I agree with @Rory the way to fix your `fed up` state is through participation and then through moderation. You, OP, are the solution.

Comment: -1 Mods are already way too active on this site.  What the site needs is less modding and more participation from normal posters.

Comment: @WarrenDew Moderators _must_ deal with content that community moderation is not willing or able to handle, that's literally our job. I am confident that all the current mod team would be happy to see more "normal posters" stepping up, but dealing with that issue is more complex than a comment-length discussion can handle.

Comment: @Erica "Mods are already way too active" is not the same as "mods should do nothing".  There is an appropriate level of moderation, but currently a fair proportion of questions get mod closed which should not be closed, deterring people from posting and keeping the traffic too low.

Comment: Then bring that up as a meta question (on a question-by-question basis, if necessary) -- mods are guided by community preferences, which are expressed via meta, and if you're seeing a pattern that you don't like, let us know and let the rest of the community chime in. I'd particularly love to see stats on question closure vs. traffic. Seriously, we can't do our job well without input.

Comment: Absolutely! If you disagree with the general view expressed by the community that mods don't close things fast enough, raise meta posts - then the community can weighty in, and us mods follow the community consensus. But don't do it by commenting on answers on other posts.